# problem compiling perl under AIX

Tags: perl, gcc, aix

I'm trying to compile the latest version of perl under AIX 5.3 and having issues.  I'm using gcc 4.2.0.  I don't have the IBM XL C compiler available.

I would happily use a pre-compiled version of perl but I need to be able to compile CPAN modules.

```
Running Mkbootstrap for threads::shared ()  
        chmod 644 shared.bs  
        rm -f ../../lib/auto/threads/shared/shared.so  
        gcc -maix32  -Wl,-bhalt:4 -Wl,-G -Wl,-bI:../../perl.exp -Wl,-bE:shared.exp -Wl,-bnoentry -lc -lm -L/usr/local/lib shared.o  -o ../../lib/auto/threads/shared/shared.so
        chmod 755 ../../lib/auto/threads/shared/shared.so  
         cp shared.bs ../../lib/auto/threads/shared/shared.bs  
        chmod 644 ../../lib/auto/threads/shared/shared.bs  
          ./perl -f -Ilib pod/buildtoc --build-toc -q  
Can't load 'lib/auto/re/re.so' for module re: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_av_fetch was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_av_len was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_av_push was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_av_store was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_bytes_to_utf8 was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_call_list was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
rtld: 0712-001 Symbol Perl_ckwarn was referenced
      from module lib/auto/re/re.so(), but a runtime definition
      of the symbol was not found.  
        0509-021 Additional errors occurred but are not reported. at lib/XSLoader.pm line 70.  
 at lib/re.pm line 69  
Compilation failed in require at lib/Text/Wrap.pm line 50.  
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Text/Wrap.pm line 50.  
Compilation failed in require at pod/buildtoc line 11.  
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at pod/buildtoc line 11.  
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 8.  

Stop.
```

Comment: Isn't AIX 5.3 out of support, these days?  And what do you regard as the latest version of Perl?  5.12.2?

Comment: I recently built Perl 5.12.1 on AIX 6.1 with GCC 4.2.1 without problem.  It is unusual to run into the problem so late in the build process.  I was using the system loader, not GNU binutils...what are you using?

Comment: Do you need threads enabled? You might have better results turning that feature off.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not entirely clear from IBM's web site, but best I can tell AIX 5.3 is supported through April 2012. (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/systemsp/lifecycle/) By most recent version of perl I meant 5.12.3.  I was using the system linker, not binutils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen pware.hvcc.edu?  William Jojo not only provides a lot of precompiled stuff, but he gives general directions on the options he used.  For exampled, to compile perl5 on 32bit AIX 5.3, he used [this recipe](http://pware.hvcc.edu/download/build-scripts/32/perl/doit).  You have to adjust for where your libraries are located, but I find these are really handy starting points.

Comment: Ultimately this is what I ended up doing.  I didn't realize he had the build scripts out there but I installed the package and then used "perl -V" to get hints about what options to use.

Answer (score 1):

These [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlaix.html#Compiling-Perl-5-on-AIX) might help.

Clearly, compiling Perl with `gcc` is going to be problematic, but it's doable.

Have you read this doc and the INSTALL doc and followed all of those directions?

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly compile CPAN modules without compiling your own Perl. Why not just do that?

Comment: You need the right compiler, and the standard Perl on AIX is built with xlc, and the OP does not have xlc.  That means that the OP must build a Perl with the compiler they do have - which is GCC.  Trying to change compilers after Perl is built is essentially undoable.

Comment: Right, I tried that and got all kinds of errors because perl was built with a different compiler.